# Two ndarray implicitly and automatically equal to each other even without explicitly specifying with the command

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am confused by the following output of the codes:

```
import numpy as np

numStates = 4
v1 = np.zeros( numStates, dtype = float)    
v2 = np.zeros( numStates, dtype = float )
d1 = np.array([0.24, 0.16, 0.08, 0.8])
d2 = np.array([0.56, 0.64, 0.72, 0.0])
payoff = np.array( [ 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0 ] )
# to index interior point
indexVet = np.arange(1, 3, 1)

stopit = False
maxIter = 10
count = 0
while not stopit:
    count = count + 1
    print('Before update v2[0]')
    print('v2' + str(v2))
    print('v1' + str(v1))
    v2[0] = d1[0] * v1[0] + d2[0] * v1[1]
    print('After update v2[0]')
    print('v2' + str(v2))
    print('v1' + str(v1))    
    valueFlush = payoff[indexVet] + v1[0] 
    valueWait = d1[indexVet] * v1[indexVet] + d2[indexVet] * v1[indexVet + 1]
    v2[indexVet] = np.maximum( valueFlush, valueWait )
    v2[numStates - 1] = payoff[numStates-1] +  v1[0]
    if ( ( np.max( v2 - v1 ) < 0.0001 ) or ( count > maxIter ) ):
        stopit = True        
    else:
        v1 = v2
```

Here I try to use "while not" to control my loop, then what I see from the output is when I execute the line "v2[0] = d1[0] * v1[0] + d2[0] * v1[1]", v2 value goes automatically to v1, that is like the command "v1 = v2" is executed implicitly. I try to rename the variables, not helping. Anyone has any idea about why v2 equal to v1 after I execute "v2[0] = d1[0] * v1[0] + d2[0] * v1[1]"? Thanks!

Comment: what's `count`? This code fails for me...

Comment: But, you have a `v1 = v2` in an `else` branch....

Comment: Did you notice that your program includes the line `v1 = v2`? You don't have two arrays after that executes; you have two references to one array.

Comment: Try `v1 = v2.copy()`

Comment: Thanks @user2357112 and @hpaulj! That's the reason why I have v1 and v2 to be the same all the time after the first while loop. I need to use v1 = v2.copy() to assign the equality of values, not asking they referring to the same array! Problem now solved!

Answer (score 0):

your indentation is incorrect

```
else:
    v1 = v2
```

should line up with the while, not with the if